# What does "flying" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

The word "flying" usually has a meaning of moving fast through the air..., but in football (soccer) context what does it mean?

Nothing to critique from Palace's side there. Just Spurs' attack linking-up the way they should have been all season. Incredible ability in that attack.

Spurs are **flying** now, building attack after attack. Doherty crosses in towards Kane who can't quite beat Cahill. Reguilon reaches the rebound at the back-post, but Guita blocks easily

Comment: It means exactly the same thing, in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: @stangdon so what does it mean in a metaphorical sense?

Comment: @Jembot It would be really great if you could fill out your biography.  I'm sure I'm not the only one here who would like to know a bit about your background and your interest in football, and the use of football commentary for English learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fly verb (MOVE QUICKLY) to move or go quickly or suddenly: Theo was
> startled when the door flew open. Saying she was late, Cathy flew by
> me and ran outside. The summer seems to have flown by (= passed
> quickly). https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fly

This can mean that they are literally running quickly but in this context it probably means that they are making fast progress in the game.